# Magento: How to use admin configforms in frontend?

Tags: magento, configuration, frontend, backend, adminhtml

I have an extension which should give the users (logged in as an Admin in the magento backend) the ability to change some configs in the frontend area. I want to have a link in the frontend which loads the config area via ajax and gives the user the possibility to edit&save this config in the loaded div. I want to use the magento backend forms for this so i don't have to code the forms myself.

My current approach has the link on the pages and loads via ajax the correct backend page (e.g. System > Configuration > Design). For this approach I created a Controller which extends the Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action. This Controller get the params from the ajax request and uses an action (like the editAction of the class Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController) to get the right config page in the backend.

My Problems are:
- showing only the correct Area (I just want the user to edit only the section "themes" under System > Configuration > Design) everything else should be not available... so how to remove all the information around this config section?

- The form needs the JS-variable Form_Key. How to get the current Form_Key (in the frontend)?
- After the ajax has loaded the content the form doesnt get initialized correctly. So if I'm trying to submit the form my firebug says "JS-Error: configForm is not defined". How to solve this form initialising ? Any ideas?

I really hope anybody here can give me a hint how to solve this problems to get the backend config work in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but it should be enough to get you on the right track:

### Output only a specific block

In the frontend most blocks are instantiated via layout XML. In the `adminhtml` area this is different, so you need to work with PHP instantiation much more.

In your AJAX action I assume you are currently calling `loadLayout()` and `renderLayout()`.
To only output a specific section use this instead:

```
public function yourAjaxAction()
{
    // assuming the required config section is set in the AJAX request
    $sectionCode = $this->getRequest()->getParam('section');
    $sections = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config')->getSections();
    $blockName = (string)$sections->frontend_model;
    if (empty($blockName)) {
        $blockName = Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit::DEFAULT_SECTION_BLOCK;
    }
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($blockName)->initForm();

    // Set the AJAX response content
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
}
```

### The form key

The form key can be fetched via

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()
```

It must be present in the form posted back to the server. You can use the following code to create a HTML hidden field with the formkey:

```
// If loadLayout() was called:
$formkeyHtml = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('formkey')->toHtml();

// If working without layout XML:
$formkeyHtml = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template', 'formkey')
    ->setTemplate('formkey.phtml') // adminhtml theme formkey
    //->setTemplate('core/formkey.phtml') // frontend theme formkey
    ->toHtml();
```

### Add configForm JavaScript

The `configForm` variable is an JS `varienForm` object of the DOM element containing the config fields.
It is instantiated using:

```
// config_edit_form is the CSS id
configForm = new varienForm('config_edit_form');
```

The `varienForm` declaration is in the file *js/varien/form.js*.
There also is some additional javascript used by the system configuration. Magento always adds in these blocks to set up the system config JS environment:

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('js')->append(
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/template')
        ->setTemplate('system/shipping/ups.phtml')
);
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('js')->append(
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/template')
        ->setTemplate('system/config/js.phtml')
);
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('js')->append(
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/template')
        ->setTemplate('system/config/applicable_country.phtml')
);
```

I hope that gets you started.